# How to download more details of map image of Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, zooming

These are the problems that i'm experiencing with Google Maps while i'm developing my first Android app:

[image]

[image]

This is the code i wrote:

```
public class MapViewer extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapviewer);

    MapFragment mf = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mappa = mf.getMap();
    mappa.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LatLng pos = new LatLng(40.9153398, 14.7897205);
    mappa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Prova").snippet("Questo è un test").icon(null).position(pos));
}

private GoogleMap mappa;
```

}

What is wrong?

Comment: In my exp, the map always download itself to a point that just enough for the viewer to see on the screen

Comment: Sorry i don't understand, what do you mean? As you can see it doesn't zoom, the image of Italy is low quality...

Comment: What I meant by download itself is that, wait a little longer then the app will eventually download the full map relates to your current view

Comment: I wait for half an hour under wifi connection but nothing changed...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your app. Maps V2 will use the tiles it has, zoomed in or out, while downloading better tiles in the background. Once those tiles arrive, the map will switch to them. How fast this will be depends upon your Internet connection, general Internet congestion, problems with Google's map tiles servers, etc.

Comment: I tried to wait for half an hour and the map keeps to be the same. I have no problems with internet connection. How to figure out the cause of this?

Comment: @smartmouse: "How to figure out the cause of this?" -- get a job with Google. There is nothing in your code that has an impact here.